# Snowflake-S3: Ingesting two types of files (from the same S3 bucket) to two different tables

Tags: amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I currently have an S3 bucket with two different types of JSON files: resource.json and metadata.json. This is the structure of our bucket:

bucket foo:

- a/b/resource.json
- a/b/metadata.json
- c/d/resource.json
- c/d/metadata.json

I would like to ingest each type file to its corresponding table (like resource.json --> resource table, metadata.json --> metadata table) but I can only use one SQS queue per bucket.

Given I have one bucket, two stages, two tables, two pipes (one stage/pipe/table per JSON file type), is there a way to configure Snowflake to read from the S3 bucket and put the contents of each file into the right table?

**Right now I have this:**

resource table in snowflake:

- entry from a/b/resource.json
- *entry from a/b/metadata.json*
- entry from c/d/resource.json
- *entry from c/d/metadata.json*

metadata table in snowflake:

- *entry from a/b/resource.json*
- entry from a/b/metadata.json
- *entry from c/d/resource.json*
- entry from c/d/metadata.json

*Italics*: the entries I don't want in those tables

**I would like to achieve this:**

resource table in snowflake:

- entry from a/b/resource.json
- entry from c/d/resource.json

metadata table in snowflake:

- entry from a/b/metadata.json
- entry from c/d/metadata.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just needed to add this line to each pipe's SQL:
`PATTERN='.*/<metadata or resource>[.]json'`

So the Pipe's SQL statement would look like this:

```
COPY INTO <table> FROM (
    SELECT <fields> FROM @<stage>
)
PATTERN='.*/<metadata or resource>[.]json';
```